# 3D-Data in Geoportal Masterportal

Tags: 3d

i am using Masterportal V. 2.39.0 (https://www.masterportal.org/). I have some Triangulated Irregular Network data (TIN) and want to show them in a 3D Map in my Masterportal. You can read that it is possible to show 3D data but i cant find how to implement it. In Portalconfig.menu.tool.modeler3D there is somethin with 3d but I dont think a tool s what I need.

I tried the 3D Modeler anyway to see what happens, but it did not show up in my Website as a tool (dont know why), so I couldnt, even test it. The other tools showed up.

```
"tools": {
        "name": "Werkzeuge",
        "children": {
          "gfi": {
            "name": "Informationen abfragen",
            "active": true
          },
          "coordToolkit": {
            "name": "Koordinaten"
          },
          "measure": {
            "name": "Strecke / Fläche messen"
          },
          "draw": {
            "name": "Zeichnen / Schreiben"
          },
          "fileImport": {
            "name": "Datei Import"
          },
          "saveSelection": {
            "name": "Auswahl speichern"
          },
          "modeler3D": {
        "name": "translate#common:menu.tools.modeler3D"
          }
```

Hope you can help me how to integrate 3d Data.

Best regards
Paul